# Automatically workflow do not start

Tags: workflow

We have a huge sharepoint list which restore more than 8000 items, there were 4 automatically starting workflows on this list. we made a change in list datasheet view for 600 items. after that, all the workflows remain at the starting point in all of our sharepoint list. Is there any issue on our services or ...?

Comment: Check SharePoint timer service is running or not

Comment: They will all be completed eventually, SharePoint is protecting itself by throttling the requests, per the referenced TechNet article below.

Answer (score 2):

There is limit of workflows that can be started at the same time.

Microsoft documentation :

> 15 is the maximum number of workflows allowed to be executing against
>   a content database at the same time, excluding instances that are
>   running in the timer service. When this threshold is reached, new
>   requests to activate workflows will be queued to be run by the
>   workflow timer service later. As non-timer execution is completed, new
>   requests will count against this threshold. This is limit can be
>   configured by using the Set-SPFarmConfig Windows PowerShell cmdlet.
>   For more information, see Set-SPFarmConfig.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Workflow